# Why doesn't IntelliJ pick up Thymeleaf template source folder?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

First of all: everything runs perfectly. So the technical side is ok. But unfortunately, IntelliJ moans that it can't find the views, even though they are displayed correctly:

```
Cannot resolve MVC view 'index'
```

The thing is, I have a Spring Boot application with one templates folder on the classpath. Within this templates folder I have 2 other folders, one for email templates and one for web views. Here the configuration for the web views:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class ThymeleafWebConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(MessageSource htmlTemplateMessageSource) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(htmlTemplateMessageSource);
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/web/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(0);
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

Curiously, IntelliJ stops whining as soon as I specify the full path within the templates folder, eg: `web/index` - which of course is not valid, since the first subfolder `web` is already covered by the prefix.

Also: the `Web Resource Directory` in `Project Settings` is set as well as a correct `Spring Facet`. `Invalidate Caches` didn't help either.

#### My question is:

Is there anything I can do to help IntelliJ on its way?

**Many thanks for any help**

Comment: If possible, please upload your project at https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the UploadID here. This way we could fully understand your project setup

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I've put together a simple project that shows that the views are not found correctly. There is a screenshot in the root folder as proof. Upload ID: 2023_07_10_FyKijoqR4jDbccjjKDNdYY

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it from my side in build 2023.1.3 (see Help | About) Try using the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: Clicking on "Reload All Maven Projects" in the Maven tool window may also help

Comment: Currently I'm running v2022.3.3. Reload Maven Projects dind't help. Since I had a bad experience with updating IntelliJ a year ago or so, I'll stick with this problem by now and will take a look into it the next time I am brave enough to upgrade the IDE. Many thanks for your reply - at least I now know that it should work as expected with the latest version.